# debug APK parsing error (generate by click android studio run button)

Tags: android, android-studio, parsing, apk, adb

I had developed app on android studio 3.0.1, but I got a error when I installed the apk to my cellphone.
Cellphone connect mac by usb, click run button

[image]

,the apk will installed and run no error. But if I copy the apk in finder (like this)

[image]

to cellphone and install it in phone, there will be an error "APK parsing error".
If install apk by "adb install xxx.apk" ，when open the app, it will crash and logcat as follow:

```
12-20 16:35:09.562 14658-14658/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-20 16:35:09.562 14658-14658/? I/art: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
12-20 16:35:09.614 14658-14658/com.xxx.xxx I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
12-20 16:35:09.620 14658-14658/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 14658
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.xxx-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxx.xxx-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.xxx.xxx-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1570)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.xxx-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxx.xxx-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.xxx.xxx-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
                                                                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1083)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1570) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832) 
12-20 16:35:09.624 14658-14658/com.xxx.xxx I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14658 SIG: 9
```

But if click Bulid>Build APK(s) , then copy the apk in same folder (this : [apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcOcs.png))to cellphone, it will install and run with no error...

is it a bug in android studio?

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: share manifest file

Comment: I think it's nothing to do with manifest file, because I can run it with no error by clicking Build->Build APK(s) or wait it installed automatic when click run button

Answer (score 0):

In new version VS, You shold use "Bulid Apk" menu option to generate the product apk :)
[image]

Comment: I know it would be work by click Bulid>Build APK(s) ,  but what's the reason for clicking run button not work?  the apk name(app-debug.apk) and path all in same.

Answer (score 0):

try with disable `Instant Run` . it find at

Run Goto File -> Settings -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Uncheck the checkbox for instant run

before this `uninstall` previous app from device.